# How can I sort columns name in a graph

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly

I am trying to cleaning modifying and visualisation data.

One one of the column has string data and when I visualise the columns python automatically sort the columns like an alphabetically.

[image]

so do we have any option to sorting columns in a graph without changing data?

Here you are this is code for this plot:

```
a = pd.pivot_table(df, values='ID', index= ['HOUSE_INCOME'], columns=['HMOWN'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0
b = a.div(a.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0)
b.iplot(kind = 'bar', barmode='stack')
```

Comment: Can you add an example how your variable `b` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The columns seem to be in alphabetical order.  If you want to use a custom order for a pandas dataframe, you can just do as in this example.

Say df has columns 'a','b','c','d'.

For custom order:

```
df = df[['c','d','a','b']]
```

For checking the names of columns in your dataframe:

```
list(df.columns.values)
```